# eventListener doesn't fire/doesn't bind properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api, jquery-events, mouseclick-event

I've been messing around with YouTube API to make a button that copies the video ID on click using jQuery. I have no idea why, I don't get any Javascript errors and after hours (actually been working on this problem for 2 days), I still haven't figured out why does the `eventListener` doesn't fire.

The `eventListener` is bound at the end of the function, which is fired when you hit a search button. Each time you click on the search button or on the next page/ previous page buttons, they fire the `makeRequest` function. Somehow, though, the function triggered by the `eventListener` never fires (the function code isn't in this parcel of code itself, but it's actually just console.log's). Can anyone help? Would be really appreciated <3

```
function makeRequest(e) {
 $('#search-container')[0].innerHTML = '';
 ytSearchResults = [];
        var q = $('#query').val();
        var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
                   q: q,
                part: 'snippet',
                maxResults: 15,
                pageToken: ytPage,
                type: 'video',
                safeSearch: 'none',
                videoSyndicated: 'true'
        });
        request.execute(function(response) {
                var str = response.result;
                ytNextPage = str.nextPageToken;
                ytPrevPage = str.prevPageToken;
                for(i=0;i<str.items.length;i++){
                  $('#search-container')[0].innerHTML += '<br><a href="https:youtube.com/watch?v=' + str.items[i].id.videoId + '" target="_blank"><image src='+str.items[i].snippet.thumbnails.default.url+'></image></a><br><button id="'+str.items[i].id.videoId+'" class="NCScopiable">'+str.items[i].snippet.title+'</button>';
                  ytSearchResults.push(str.items[i].id.videoId);
                }
                
                $('#search-container')[0].innerHTML += '<br><div id="button-changePage"><span id="button-prevPage" style="color:blue;cursor:pointer;margin:5px"><u>Previous Page</u></span><span id="button-nextPage" style="color:blue;cursor:pointer;margin:5px"><u>Next Page</u></span>';
                if(e&&ytCurPage>0){
                  $('#button-prevPage')[0].style.display = 'block';
                  $('#button-nextPage')[0].style.display = 'block';
                } else {
                  ytCurPage = 0;
                  $('#button-prevPage')[0].style.display = 'none';
                }
                $('#button-prevPage').on('click',function(){ytCurPage-=1;ytPage=ytPrevPage;makeRequest(true);});
                $('#button-nextPage').on('click',function(){ytCurPage+=1;ytPage=ytNextPage;makeRequest(true);});
                console.log('Current ytCurPage value: '+ytCurPage);
        });
        $('.NCScopiable').on('click',cTWI);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the line

```
$('.NCScopiable').on('click',cTWI);
```

Is being executed before the code inside the callback passed to `request.execute` has fired, so those elements don't exist yet. Thus `$('.NCScopiable')` is returning nothing.

Move that line into the last line of your callback code and you should be good to go, for example:

```
    request.execute(function(response) {
            var str = response.result;
            ytNextPage = str.nextPageToken;
            ytPrevPage = str.prevPageToken;

            // ...code removed for brevity...
            // this was the code that is actually creating the elements with
            // the NCScopiable class

            console.log('Current ytCurPage value: '+ytCurPage);
            $('.NCScopiable').on('click',cTWI);
    });
```

Comment: Worked, idk how but. Thanks!

Comment: @Nuvm - You are very welcome. You may want to reread my answer, as it states quite plainly why the original did not work and why the changed version does. Also, it is customary to accept the answer if it answers your question and solves the problem. Thanks!